# Not able to connect to Hbase with java api

Tags: hbase, apache-zookeeper

I am running `Hbase` on standalone cloudera vm. I am just trying to connect to hbase from my java code but getting this exception all time. I have not done any entry in the `hbase-site.xml`. Also I have Hbase and zookeper up and running. Below is exception I am getting:

> ming-2.6.0-cdh5.7.0.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-hs-plugins.jar:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/.//hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient-tests.jar
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/native
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:java.compiler=
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.name=Linux
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.arch=amd64
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:os.version=2.6.32-573.el6.x86_64
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.name=cloudera
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.home=/home/cloudera
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Client environment:user.dir=/home/cloudera
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ZooKeeper: Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=90000 watcher=hconnection-0x2da61880x0, quorum=localhost:2181, baseZNode=/hbase
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Socket connection established, initiating session, client: /127.0.0.1:56535, server: quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session establishment complete on server quickstart.cloudera/127.0.0.1:2181, sessionid = 0x1562b869790000e, negotiated timeout = 40000
>   16/08/03 23:04:33 INFO mapreduce.HFileOutputFormat: Looking up current regions for table user;hconnection-0x2da6188
>   org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.RetriesExhaustedException: Failed after attempts=36, exceptions:
>   Wed Aug 03 23:05:21 PDT 2016, null, java.net.SocketTimeoutException: callTimeout=60000, callDuration=68660: row 'user,,00000000000000' on table 'hbase:meta' at region=hbase:meta,,1.1588230740, hostname=quickstart.cloudera,60020,1469171048401, seqNum=0

This is my java code .

```
public int run(String[] args) throws Exception {
        int result=0;
        String outputPath = args[1];        
        Configuration configuration = getConf();
        configuration.set("data.seperator", DATA_SEPERATOR);        
        configuration.set("hbase.table.name",TABLE_NAME);       
        configuration.set("COLUMN_FAMILY_1",COLUMN_FAMILY_1);       
        configuration.set("COLUMN_FAMILY_2",COLUMN_FAMILY_2);       
        Job job = new Job(configuration);       
        job.setJarByClass(HBaseBulkLoadDriver.class);       
        job.setJobName("Bulk Loading HBase Table::"+TABLE_NAME);        
        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);     
        job.setMapOutputKeyClass(ImmutableBytesWritable.class);     
        job.setMapperClass(HBaseBulkLoadMapper.class);      
        FileInputFormat.addInputPaths(job, args[0]);        
        FileSystem.getLocal(getConf()).delete(new Path(outputPath), true);      
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(outputPath));      
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Put.class);      
        HFileOutputFormat.configureIncrementalLoad(job, new HTable(configuration,TABLE_NAME));      
        job.waitForCompletion(true);        
        if (job.isSuccessful()) {
            HBaseBulkLoad.doBulkLoad(outputPath, TABLE_NAME);
        } else {
            result = -1;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: can you show the java code that results in this error?

Comment: I have added java code to access hbase

Comment: Where do you execute the Java code? directly on Quickstart VM? or remote? and can you tell me the Hbase version?

Comment: I am executing java code Quickstart VM ...Version is 1.2.0-cdh5.8.0

Answer (score 0):

Zookeeper is being resolved via localhost and connecting fine.  Can you resolve quickstart.cloudera?  My guess it is a DNS issue since the call times out to quickstart.cloudera.  Does that make sense?